Codabar in AVFoundation
We have an existing barcode scanner app, but a customer wants the ability to scan codabar barcodes.
I read AVFoundation now supports codabar but when I add it to the barcode types it does not work.
private let barcodeTypes = [
    AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.code39,
    AVMetadataObject.codabar,
    AVMetadataObject.code128,
    AVMetadataObject.qr
]

Do I need to do anything else?  I made sure I have the latest version of xcode.  This is an exsisting app that runs off of AVFoundation and the other barcode types work.
